# PostgreSQL - how to find special characters, white space, extra tabs, and carriage returns in text fields?

Tags: regex, postgresql, special-characters, whitespace

I am trying to check database columns in PostgreSQL for special characters, white space (more than one space), extra tabs, and carriage returns.  The idea for me is to find special characters such as (e.g., +," ",`, /,', etc.).  I want to count how many occurrences there are of these values.  I am fairly new to PostgreSQL and regular expressions.

Example,

```
roadmap/plan
Smith, Tom  (2 spaces after Tom)
applicant's
    see me (tab)
Q4  2024
FY2024+
```

So far I have tried the following SQL to find these values.

```
select col1 from  table_name
where col1  ~*  '[^A-Za-z0-9&\(\)\| \''.-\\s*\s*|\s+y\s+]+';
```

However, I am getting back records I do not care about like if there is a . character.

Example,

```
Dr. Tom Smith
```

I have also tried:

```
select col1 from  table_name
where col1  ~* '[^A-Za-z0-9^\\''\-#+~_\t\r]';
```

I still get back records I don't care about:

Example,

```
Q4 2024
Tom Smith
```

My criteria is find:

- Quotation marks (Single and Double)
- Back Ticks
- <,>
- Apostrophes
- Plus signs +
- {}
- &
- - 
- |
- Extra Tabs
- Carriage Returns
- Spaces between words
- Backslash or Forward Slash
- Piping
- Alphanumeric values are: a-z or A-Z
- Numeric values are: 0-9

What am I missing or need to take out of the regex?

Comment: Generally the special ASCII characters are `[!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_\`{|}~]` or condensed is  `[!-/:-@\[-\`{-~]` are you trying to match these ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find special characters like [', " ",#,%, \, ~, +, `(back tick), $, <,>, {},|,@].  I am also looking for carriage returns, extra tabs, space between words, and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces are allowed, so put them in your character class, but add a check for doubled spaces:

```
where col1 ~* '[^A-Za-z0-9^\\''\-#+~_\t\r\n ]|\\s\\s+';
```

Comment: I am still getting a result that contains records that do not have any issues.  I tried removing the A-Z a-z 0-9 because I just want to find the outliers.

Comment: Please show examples of values that don't have any issues but are matching?

Comment: try adding `\n` to the regex. I've changed the answer.

Comment: I see names without any extra spaces or other issues.  I want to only get back records that have the banned special characters or issues listed above in my question. 

Smith, Troy
Julie Ryan